# Trouble extracting year from date field for computed field

Tags: 7, entities

I have a date field, 'field_date', from which I need to extract the year.  The date format is yyyy-mm-dd, so I figured the following would do it:

```
$date = array_pop(array_pop(field_get_items($entity_type, $entity, 'field_date')));
$year = explode("-", $date)[0];
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $year;
```

This gives me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['` Am I not getting the date string correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function array dereferencing was [added in PHP 5.4](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), you must be using an older version.

To fix:

```
$parts = explode("-", $date);
$year = $parts[0];
```